# Create an array of objects from HTML using jQuery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have number of divs with class row, each div contains divs with class header and body.

Now, i would like to read the value of inputs from header and body and store them in an array of objects like below.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <input type="checkbox" value="11">
            <input type="checkbox" value="12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
            <input type="checkbox" value="2">
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <input type="checkbox" value="21">
            <input type="checkbox" value="22">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
            <input type="checkbox" value="3">
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <input type="checkbox" value="31">
            <input type="checkbox" value="32">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Desired Output
I want to generate (with jQuery) an array of objects similar to the following:**

```
[
    {
        "line1": 1,
        "line2": [11, 12]
    },
    {
        "line1": 2,
        "line2": [21, 22]
    },
    {
        "line1": 3,
        "line2": [31, 32]
    }
]
```

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: @AlivetoDie: i am new to javascript. So bit confused to create this JSON.

Comment: so, take a ook about jQuery selector, to select elements like this `$("input[type='checkbox']")`. then you'll have a collection of jQuery HTML objects, you can use `each()` to iterate over then and then get its values. You can also check the `parent()` of the inputs. Just research a little bit on the jQuery docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick!

```
let data = [];

//loop over each element with row class
$.each($(".row"), function(i, row) {

  //get the value of the header input within that row
  let headerVal = parseFloat($(row).find(".header input").val());


  let bodyVals = [];

  //loop over each body input within the row
  $.each($(row).find(".body input"), function(i, body) {

    //push the value of each body input into tho bodyVals array
    bodyVals.push(parseFloat($(body).val()));
  });

  //create an object containing the header and body values
  //and push it to the data array
  data.push({
    line1: headerVal,
    line2: bodyVals
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/so6bzwn7/26/

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It functions exactly as requested and has been shown to work in JSFiddle.

Comment: Not my downvote, but throwing a bunch of overly complicated code without any explanation at a beginner isn't helpful...

Comment: @Andreas Added comments